# Why the Unloaded event of UserControl would not fire?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

I just found a huge memory leak in a simple Windows Store app I'm developing.

It turned out that I've put a UserControl in the `ItemTemplate` of a ListView, and hooked the `Unloaded` event of the UserControl to detach some event handler.

I've expected that when the items of the ListView are **cleared**, the `Unloaded` event of the UserControl would fire, but it won't! But when I **removed** the items one by one, the `Unloaded` event of the UserControl will fire as expected.

Can any one give me some advice about this? Or where should I put the clean-up code besides hooking the `Unloaded` event. Any idea would be appreciated! thx! Below is the code snippet:

To be simplified, the `ItemTemplate` of the ListView is:

```
 <DataTemplate>
      <local:MyUserControl1 />
 </DataTemplate>
```

and MyUserControl1 is just an empty UserControl:

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Unloaded += MyUserControl1_Unloaded;
    }

    private void MyUserControl1_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MyUserControl1_Unloaded...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the default ListView, it will enable the UI virtualization. When you call `Clear()` method, the ListView will do some special treatments, it actually hasn't removed these items(I believe you also have found this situation).

You can see the ActualHeight of ListView in live visual tree(it's set 0). That's why you cannot see listview on UI.

[image]

So the workaround is to use `Remove()` method or `listview.Itemsource=null`. You can also try to disable the UI virtualization. E.g, using the `StackPanel` as ItemsPanelTemplate.

Comment: yes,you're correct. It's the designed mechanism of ListView ui virtualization. I'll continue using ui virtualization and have found a solution to control the cache size. This is my thread on msdn:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92f76519-f139-4c94-ae5e-630f0abda66e/memory-leak-with-listview-ui-virtualization?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: The problem is still there. I've tried both methods:1)removing all the items one by one(instead of clearing);2)let listview.Itemsource = null. There's still some item retained by the ListView, which I expect that all items are removed from memory.

Comment: @SimonFisher I refer to the code on your MSDN thread to test. I cannot reproduce this issue. When I call `Clear()`,`Remove()` method, the items would be removed. I cannot find it in SnapShot report.

Comment: I ran the performance profiler several times again, each time I got the same result: there'll be 75 or 76 items retained in the memory(I've clicked Force GC). Still trying to find the reason.